# Why is my Nikon Coolpix S3100 showing "File contains no image data" when I try to view old photos?

Tags: nikon, preview

I've got a Nikon Coolpix S3100 that is now showing:

> File contains no image data

when I try to view *some* of the photos on the SD card from the camera. Viewing the photos on the computer shows the images just fine, and the other photos on the card appear OK so I'm 100% sure that the card isn't corrupted in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little research has revealed the cause of this problem.

The problem was only affecting those photos taken in portrait mode that had also been rotated on the computer to make them easier to view. By mistake I'd rotated them on the SD card rather than copy them first and rotate the copy (which I normally do). The Coolpix doesn't seem to store orientation data (reading the EXIF data shows "Normal" for the orientation regardless of the actual orientation of the photo) and it must look at the dimensions of the image and expect them to be particular values.

Rotating the image back to "landscape" makes it viewable on the camera again.

Comment: Most digital cameras require that images be in **landscape orientation** and **contain an embedded thumbnail** in the Exif. If either of these two conditions are not met, an error is likely to result. See [How to copy Images Back To DSLR from computer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/99271/75526) for additional issues regarding images located on memory cards.

Answer (score 4):

Where you get the "File contains no Image data" after viewing files on your PC is generally down to various viewer and edit programs ADDING information to the original file. A simple test to see if it is the SD card that is corrupted is to put it into your PC and see if you can read all the files. If you can then the SD card if fine.

Microsoft Photo Viewer adds "Padding" information to various sections of the original JPEG file to allow for Metadata data such as Ratings, Tags, Descriptions etc to be added without having to rewrite the whole file.  Unfortunately this action by MS then means that you cannot view the file on your camera !!  A simple question if we wanted the Metadata to be added prior to saving would have saved us all a lot of time and frustration.