# How can modified images be displayed on a Nikon camera?

Tags: nikon, jpeg, presentation

I made changes to my RAW images in Lightroom and exported them as JPEG to save on an SD card which I inserted into my camera. When I tried to show the pictures to my family and friends, I got the following error: **"Cannot display this file"**.

I have read very simillar questions like [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29288/coolpix-p50-file-contains-no-image-data-after-rotation) or [that](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/why-is-my-nikon-coolpix-s3100-showing-file-contains-no-image-data-when-i-try-t) but am yet to figure a solution.

**Has any of you overcome the problem and written correct metadata to the files?**

Showing images directly from my Nikon D600 camera is much more convenient for me as I then do not have to lug my notebook around.

Answer (score 6):

It is likely the structure of the data in the JPEG file and not related to metadata or EXIF information.

I'm not fimiliar with lightroom specifically, but when you save JPEGs there are options for things like 'optimization', 'huffman encoding', 'progressive', etc. Try disabling all of those. Your camera probably only knows how to deal with a specific set of parameters for the JPEG. Lightroom will have used a JPEG formatting parameter that isn't compatible with your camera.

In Photoshop the 'optimization' option has to do with how it arranges the huffman codes. A non-standard set of *optimized* huffman codes can make the file smaller, but won't be compatible with some proprietary devices.

The only way to tell for sure is to experiment by saving various JPEGs to the card with different settings. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, the problem can be in these JPEG encodings too. I will hassle with these along with the metadata if anyone haven't found the solution. I just want to avoid this "try & error" :)

Comment: Or shoot a jpeg on the camera and find out what it uses, then you'll know for sure...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the Thumbnail — that's what really shows in the camera.  If you check the jpg files created by the camera and generated by most programs, they have thumbnails with offsets and completely different sizes. I think the camera looks for a marker for specific offset which the camera and other programs, including VIEWNX2, are able to generate.

I used the program [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) to copy the metadata of a jpg generated by Nikon, but it also copies the thumbnail,  so unfortunately the result is that the Nikon recognizes the file and displays it — but the copied thumbnail of the source file. If you find something, publish it, because this is driving me crazy.

Comment: I'm curious to see what happens if you use `jhead`'s -rgt option to recreate the thumbnail of the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Nikon software, rather than Lightroom, to convert the RAW files to jpeg. I would think there is a much greater chance those would be compatible with your Nikon camera.

Comment: Tried Nikon software (ViewNX2) which has minor editing software and SORRY...any changes to the image and it will not display on the camera (S9100 or S9300) and gives error message that there is "no image data". I am shocked, surprised and disappointed in Nikon for not insuring that their editing software is compatible with camera display.. :-(