# adobe lightroom import photo more red than original

Tags: lightroom, color, adobe, import

[image]

can anybody help to explain;
why photo become more to "red tone" after import into adobe lightroom?
is there any setting or is it normal?
please advice.

(left side is from library tab; right side from develope tab)

Comment: Did you set any Profile?

Comment: no. 1st time import photo already like this

Comment: In import you can set a lot of things, including Profile. Please check your import preset(s)

Answer (score 2):

The 'Library' tab is likely using the [jpeg preview](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/99937/15871) generated in-camera and attached to the raw file.

The develop module is probably reinterpreting the raw data based upon your choice for [default rendering](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/98371/15871).

Or vice versa, depending on your choices in Lightroom's settings options.

Comment: i believe i did not put any preset setting during importing the photo.

Comment: Then you are letting Adobe apply one for you. Every raw file must be interpreted in order to be a viewable image.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the profile embedded in any image exported from LR to allow PS to display it correctly