# Does anyone know what this diffuse pattern that appears to be in all my photos is and if it can be fixed?

Tags: canon, photo-editing

[image]

This diffuse pattern appears in all of my recent photos. I don't know what it can be. The camera is a Canon.

Comment: Is the pattern the same shape, size, and in the same location on each image? Or is it different in shape, size, or location on different images? What aperture setting was used in the example image?

Comment: It is, same size, same spot, same shape, and it seems i cannot edit it out in lightroom. I really dont know what it is. Camera never gave any problems

Comment: Also it olny appears if i edit the photos. If not it cannot be seen in the RAW setting of the photo.

Comment: Have you tried examining the camera sensor under magnification?

Comment: Strange that it would appear only when you edit images.  Does it appear in camera-produced JPEGs?

Comment: Yes,it appears that the sensor its ok. And no, it only appears in the edited ones. I think i might concluded that its more about lightroom than the camera itself.

Comment: You don’t actually see the raw file in Lightroom - simply an interpretation of it. So, are you saying that the initial image is fine, and this artifact appears only after you start adjusting things? If so, what adjustments are you making that cause this to reveal itself?

Comment: Some cameras can save information about sensor dust so that the camera can remove them during processing.  Don't know whether dust info is saved in the raw file.  If not, perhaps that is why it is absent in JPGs and previews, but appears when you attempt to process the raw.  Even though you didn't see anything when you examined the sensor, you can try using a blower to see if it changes anything.

Comment: "The camera is a Canon." A Canon **what**? A DSLR, a point-and-shoot? It matters, because we need to know if your lens is removable.

Comment: @xiota Even if the raw file contains dust delete data in the 'maker notes' section of the metadata, I doubt Adobe products would automatically use it. But they might. If so, it may be turned off in the OP's user preferences.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be something on your camera's sensor. If you have saved a "dust delete data" image and have it enabled, in camera JPEGs and previews (such as those attached to raw files) will attempt to filter it out.

When you first open a raw image in Lightroom in the preview module, you're almost certainly looking at the [in-camera generated JPEG preview image](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99936/15871) that is attached to the raw file. Once you begin editing the image, Lightroom will render a new interpretation based on the contents of the raw data, rather than the JPEG preview you were initially seeing. At this point the Canon dust delete information will not be used by Adobe Lightroom and you will see the artifact.

Comment: Seems to be quite big for a dust speck? More like some grease stain?

Comment: Yes, but the "dust delete" feature of many cameras will also (attempt to) deal with any fixed pattern on the sensor. It doesn't have to be strictly dust for the calibration shot to detect it and (attempt to) map it out.