# Prevent my Pixel 6 smartphone from auto-editing my photos

Tags: photo-editing, smartphone

I have a Google Pixel 6 that I bought mostly because of the good camera. I have to admit, for a phone, it's amazing. However, a "feature" really annoys me: it keepes automatically editing every picture I take. Like mentioned in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/smz2ou/how_to_stop_photos_from_being_automatically_edited/?rdt=45907) that I found, I can see the picture for liike 0.5 seconds after taking it, before it is permanently edited to look better.

As much as I appreciate the results most of the time, sometimes they are absolutely not called for, and I would like to avoid this feature. Is it possible?

I recorded my screen and you can see what  I am talking about here: https://i.imgur.com/yV0SizF.mp4

As you can, when I go to the picture I just took, it takes a little while and the picture is transformed permanently.

Comment: Take RAW photos and edit them later.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Good point, I just checked and RAW photos are indeed not automatically edited. It's a bit annoying not to have that on JPEGs though.

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing immediately after you trip the "shutter" is not your photo, it's a frozen grab of the last frame of the video feed the phone was showing you before you triggered the "shutter". The delay is the time it takes, based on the camera settings in force at the time the photo was taken, for the phone to process the information it has captured and display that on your screen instead.

If you're shooting JPEGs or HEIFs the camera settings for things such as contrast, color saturation, white balance, etc. are being applied to the raw data collected by the sensor. These things are more or less "baked in" when converted to JPEG or HEIF. If you're saving the raw data, then your phone is showing you the JPEG preview image that is generated and attached to the raw file. You can use a raw conversion app to edit using the raw data and by changing the settings you can come up with a different interpretation of that same raw data.

**Anytime you open a raw file and look at it on any screen, you are not viewing "THE raw file."** You are viewing [one among a near-countless number of possible interpretations](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/85871/15871) of the data in the raw file. The raw data itself contains a single (monochrome) brightness value measured by each pixel well. With Bayer masked camera sensors (the vast majority of color digital cameras use Bayer filters) each pixel well has a [color filter in front](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/87251/15871) of it that is either 'red', 'green', or 'blue' (the actual 'colors' of the filters in most Bayer Masks are anywhere from a slightly greenish-yellow to an orange-yellow for 'red", an ever so slightly yellow-green for 'green' and a blue-violet for 'blue' - [these colors more or less correspond to the center of sensitivity for the three types of cones in our retinas](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/99711/15871)).

For more about the difference between raw image data and what you see on the screen of a phone, camera, or computer please see the following existing questions and their answers here at Photo SE:

[RAW files store 3 colors per pixel, or only one?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/86170/15871)
[What does an unprocessed RAW file look like?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/105271/15871)
[Is the Preview file always the photo taken by the camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99936/15871)
[Why are my RAW images already in colour if debayering is not done yet?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/81761/15871)