# How can I use my camera to display arbitrary JPEG images from my PC in a slideshow?

Tags: sdcard, slideshow

I have a **Canon Powershot S100** that I'd like to connect to a TV to display a slideshow. I uploaded a few hundred JPEG files to an SD card, put the card in the camera, and hooked it up to the TV. However, the camera is displaying `No images found`. I tried putting the  images on the root `E:\` and `E:\DCIM\` with the same results.

The slideshow plays perfectly on the TV with the camera's original SD card, which has images the camera itself took. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/why-is-my-nikon-coolpix-s3100-showing-file-contains-no-image-data-when-i-try-t

Answer (score 1):

Cameras are often programmed to only recognize files produced by the same model. At the very least, they require images in *\DCIM\100CANON* for example. Make sure to use the exact structure of the camera and name the files with the right format, say *PICT0001.JPG*.

There is a good chance this won't work unless you copy the EXIF from another image produced by the Canon S100. You can use a tool like *exiv2* for that. Some cameras are more tolerant than others and I know that most Fuji models will display the thumbnail from other images with a gift icon on top, indicating the file comes from another camera.

Comment: I took a look at exiv2 and extracted an .exv from a working image, but exiv2 does not appear to be able to do batch inserts. With over 200 files I'd have to manually run a command per file!

Comment: exiv2 can certainly do batch operations, but even if it couldn't, there's no reason you'd have to run a command _manually_ per file -- just put it in a very simple loop. Alternately, you could use `exiftool`, which I find has easier syntax for some operations.